# Bring factor under radical in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have an expression like this in sympy (for example): `eq = 1.234113*sqrt(2.33*x0**2+1.332*x1)`. How can I force that prefactor to go under the radical? The documentation I found online so far is just for factorization but I didn't really find something for this. Thank you!

Comment: @JohanC I am not sure what you mean. How can the number "1.234113" be negative?  For example 2*sqrt(3) is always equal to sqrt(12). I want to put a number under the radical, which is explicitly positive, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy pulls out Floats to make such expressions canonical. You can put it back with

```
>>> a, b = eq.args
>>> sqrt(a**2*b.args[0], evaluate=0)
sqrt(1.88379173728726*x0**2 + 1.07691441805435*x1)
```

You can make a function that canonically puts any literal number under a radical with

```
def unfactor_radicals(eq):
    """put leading numbers in Mul under a radical, if possible

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy import sqrt, root
    >>> from sympy.abc import x
    >>> eq = -7.2*root(x, 3)**4 + 3*x*sqrt(1/x)
    >>> unfactor_radicals(eq)
    -(4.39540980178165*x)**(4/3) + x*sqrt(9/x)
    """
    from sympy import Pow, UnevaluatedExpr
    def do(m):
        args = m.args
        c = args[0]
        m = args[1:]
        if c < 0:
            s = -1
            c = -c
        else:
            s = 1
        rad = next(ordered([i for i in m if i.is_Pow and i.exp.is_Rational and i.exp.is_Integer is False]))
        i = m.index(rad)
        p = Pow(c**(1/rad.exp)*rad.base, rad.exp, evaluate=False)
        return s*UnevaluatedExpr(m.func(*(m[:i]+(p,)+m[i+1:]), evaluate=False))
    return eq.replace(
        lambda x: x.is_Mul and x.args[0].is_Number and any(
            i.is_Pow and i.exp.is_Rational and i.exp.is_Integer is False
            for i in x.args),
        lambda x: do(x))
```

It creates UnevaluatedExpr, however, and I don't know how much trouble that will create...but it may give some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for this! I assume in the second line you mean a**2, right? However it seems like sympy doesn't count the 2 expressions as equal, which complicates my code. I tried to compare eq1 = 2*sqrt(0.23*x0 + 0.1*x1) with eq2 = sqrt(0.92*x0 + 0.4*x1) and eq1 == eq2 gives False

Comment: updated answer; try use `a.equals(b)`...but don't expect too much when comparing Floats.

Comment: I looked a bit at this and it doesn't really work generally. I am reading expressions in a for loop, and not all of them have sqrt. So the above method would screw some of them up. I was hoping for some sort of function multiply_coefs(eq), that would put that coefficient under radical, but wouldn't affect normal equations i.e. 2*(3*x0+4*x1), would become 6*x0+8*x1, without having any sqrt.